# blank space on the right side of the page

Tags: html, css

I have this issue with my page right now, everything is pretty much centered and exactly like I want, but if I scroll horizontally I can see a white space on the right. I have no idea which element is doing this. I have overflow-x: hidden in the body tag.

Any tips?

[image: blank space]

http://www.os-os.co.uk/CGMATHEWS

Comment: I can't scroll horizontally. And please include relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Let me guess: Ipad? Or some other apple device? :)

Comment: @Oriol what would you call relevant other than the full html/css file?

if you highlight some text in the page you can force it to move to the right

Comment: @nevermind nop, it happens to me on my android as well! and I can reproduce the issue on chrome if I highlight the text and force it to the right... weird stuff

Comment: I can't scroll horizontally either and don't see the problem.

Comment: I can definitely see the problem in Chrome on OS X. I posted an answer below. In case you're curious, to reveal the issue, I just opened up the inspector and created a new style for `* { border: 1px solid #f00 }` which just gives every element a red border. Easy to spot.

Comment: @biip A link to the full code is not code. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Now you will fix your page and this question will become useless to future visitors.

Comment: @Oriol sorry, but I completely disagree with you. would be impossible without the full code for anyone to give any helpful tip since any page element could be causing the issue. 

also, both provided answers are perfectly useful to anyone who has a similar problem. one fixed the issue, and the other one teaches how to debug it.

Comment: @biip Well, those are the rules, explained in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't follow them, your questions may be closed. If you disagree, maybe you should ask your questions in another website which allows them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with this tag:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
```

The width of it is pushing out the right side of the page. Take a look at it in the inspector.

Comment: ok, that fixed most of it, but there's still a tiny white space left! any idea? which inspector are you using?

Comment: @biip That has to do with the carousel right-arrow. See my comment above about adding a border to all elements to make the problem visible. You can ignore the nav since it's block-level and resizes with the page.

Comment: @biip no problem! The inspector is such a fantastic tool and sometimes the hackiest things really make life so much easier. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow-x: hidden;` to your master style in style.css. It's the first declared style under the font face declarations.

Comment: Is this a hack or a fix?

Comment: Technically a fix. @biip put the overflow-x in another CSS declaration that modifies the wrong element. They have a "master style" in their style.css file that sets general styling for all elements on the page. Adding the overflow-x declaration here fixes the whitespace issue in Firefox and Chrome. Have not yet tested IE.

Comment: this works good as well, even tho it is more of a hack. but thanks, next time i'll put the overflow in the right class!